# How to get all product id from Shopify Python API

Tags: python-2.7, api, shopify

I have created one private shopify app. Which can get almost all the information with product id. But I need one option to get product id of all products in a shop with API. I have tried the option below

```
shopify.Product.find()
```

but it shows only first 50 products. But my shop has more than 2.4k products.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update as of 2019-07:** This will no longer work as it has been deprecated and subsequently removed from the Shopify API.

The replacement is detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66021065/1035897).

Original answer below

---

Shopify returns paginated responses for lists of resources. The default number of resources per page is `50`, and the default page is `1`. Your request is thus equivalent to the following:

```
shopify.Product.find(limit=50, page=1)
```

Shopify allows you to increase the limit per page to 250. Here's a helper function I use to get all of a given resource:

```
def get_all_resources(resource, **kwargs):
    resource_count = resource.count(**kwargs)
    resources = []
    if resource_count > 0:
        for page in range(1, ((resource_count-1) // 250) + 2):
            kwargs.update({"limit" : 250, "page" : page})
            resources.extend(resource.find(**kwargs))
    return resources
```

You use it like this:

```
products = get_all_resources(shopify.Product)
```

You can even pass in parameters. Your question asks specifically for the product ID- if you limit the query to only return the IDs, this will be much, much faster (as it doesn't have to pull in any of the product variants):

```
product_ids = get_all_resources(shopify.Product, fields="id")
```

Note that if you have 2.4k products, this may take some time!

Documentation:
https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. Though I could solve it after posting the question. But I liked your solution. :)

Comment: Thanks Rafayet, perhaps this will help someone else :)

Comment: Thanks Julien. This has been very helpful. Any idea how one can use this with shopify.Order? When using the function, it only returns 33 items.

Comment: Pls disregard. I figured it out.  Use `shopify.Orders.find(status="any",limit="100")`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, having trouble to make it work this case: 
`shopify.CustomerSavedSearch.find({customer_saved_search_id}).customers()`

Comment: Please note THIS WILL NOT WORK in API versions after 2019-07. The code to do it after looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66021065/1035897

Answer (score 8):

Pagination interface has changed in Shopify API, and the old "limit + page" way of doing pagination was [removed in api version 2019-07](https://shopify.dev/concepts/about-apis/versioning/release-notes/2019-07#rest-admin-api-changes).

In other words: the accepted answer by @Julien will NOT work in this api version and later.

I have re-created the function of the accepted answer using the new way of doing [relative cursor based pagination](https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/relative-pagination) here:

```
def get_all_resources(resource_type, **kwargs):
    resource_count = resource_type.count(**kwargs)
    resources = []
    if resource_count > 0:
        page=resource_type.find(**kwargs)
        resources.extend(page)
        while page.has_next_page():
            page = page.next_page()
            resources.extend(page)
    return resources
```

Comment: i am getting this error: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` do you have a solution for error?

Comment: @Clegane: I am only guessing here, but could it be that your args are invalid somehow? Did you try with less/no args for your search?

Comment: I got this error a long time ago. I think I did this using python requests. anyway thank you for the reply.

Comment: After banging my head trying to get my simple function to work in production this finally saved the day and the client is happy.

Answer (score 4):

An extension of Lennart Rolland response.

As he stated the preferred answer is no longer applicable in api version 2019-07.

I was unable to get his code sample to work, because of an error "list does not have the function has_next_page()".

So I have written an example using the 'Link' header rel='next' pagination.

```
def get_all_resources(resource):
    page_info = str()
    resources = list()
    while True:
        resources.extend(resource.find(limit=250, page_info=page_info))
        cursor = shopify.ShopifyResource.connection.response.headers.get('Link')
        if 'next' in cursor:
            page_info = cursor.split(';')[-2].strip('<>').split('page_info=')[1]
        else:
            break
    return resources
```

Comment: Forgive my amateur question, but what is the parameter you pass into this function (resource) the result of the api call or? As I believe this snippet is what I need but I cant get it to work with my call, sorry for the silly question.

Comment: There is no such thing as a silly question :-)
You need to pass the resource you want to return. So if you want to get all the products then it's "shopify.Product".
But it'd work just as well with shopify.Customer, shopify.Address, shopify.Cart etc and that is why it's parameterized. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thought this might be helpful as well:

```
def get_products():
    """
    Returns a list of all products in form of response JSON
    from Shopify API endpoint connected to storefront.

    * Note: Shopify API allows 250 pruducts per call.

    :return:
        product_list (list):    List containing all product response
                                JSONs from Shopify API.
    """

    products = []
    is_remaining = True
    i = 1
    while is_remaining:

        if i == 1:
            params = {
                "limit": 250,
                "page": i
            }

            response = requests.get(
                "{}/products.json".format(SHOPIFY_ENDPOINT),
                params=params
            )

            products.append(response.json()['products'])
            i += 1

        elif len(products[i-2]) % 250 == 0:
            params = {
                "limit": 250,
                "page": i
            }

            response = requests.get(
                "{}/products.json".format(SHOPIFY_ENDPOINT),
                params=params
            )

            products.append(response.json()['products'])
            i += 1

        else:
            is_remaining = False

    products = [products[i][j]
        for i in range(0, len(products))
        for j in range(0, len(products[i]))
    ]

    return products
```